# I have one onclick button, that needs to open three different windows based on the php variable being passed on to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php

Please help me with the syntax for the javascript function and onclick button, which would function as follows :-

I have one onclick button, that needs to open three different windows based on the php variable being passed on to a javascript function ?

Thanks !!!

`<html>`

`<body>`

`<?php`

`session_start();`

`include "desig.php";`

`?>`

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">`

`function trackOpenWindow(wheader, wname, wsize, passobj1)`

`{`

`var trackwin;`

`if (passobj1 != null)`

`{`

`if (!passobj1.closed)`

`{`

`passobj1.focus();`

`return passobj1;`

`}`

`}`

`trackwin=window.open(wheader, wname, wsize);`

`return trackwin;`

`}`

`</script>`

`<script>`

`var passobj1=null;`

`</script>`

`<button name="subject" type="submit" style= "height:250px; width:480px; float:right" onClick='javascript:passobj1=trackOpenWindow("TRACK.php", "myWin2", "height=250,width=480", passobj1 );'>TRACK</button>`

`</body>`

`</html>`

Here's my code.

Basically, desig.php can return 3 values, based on the value which it returns I want to open a window for the TRACK button.

Comment: Post relevant code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Javascript can only open 1 window on each event. If you want to open 3 windows, you need 3 onclick events. Otherwise malicious websites could open thousands of websites ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without any code we can only guess as to what you are trying to accomplish.  However, why not use a switch/case in your onClick?

```
switch(var)
case 1:
     // do something
     break;
case 2:
     // do something else
     break;
case 3:
     // last thing
     break;
default:
     // nothing matched
```

Comment: Pleased to help you;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
<?php
$myvar = 'Hello ' . $_POST['name'];
echo '<input type="btn" onlcick="mightyFunction(\"' . $myvar . '\")';
?>
```